# finish an activity that is back in the stack

Tags: android

Assume I have activities, like ACT1->ACT2>ACT3, if I open ACT4 I am having ACT1->ACT2->ACT3->ACT4. In this case I want to close ACT1, so I will have only 3 activities on my stack.
Further when I open ACT5, I want to have only ACT3->ACT4->ACT5.

I tried startActivityForResult(curActivity) and then trying to close the old activites using finishActivity(curActivity - 3) but it doesn't work.
Any help/suggestion will be very appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using an Array of Activities is doing it's job, beside the use of memory it's ok